# Is the order of view controller objects in the navigator pane relevant?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I am just beginning to develop an app using Xcode 5 and am very much a newbie.
I have a project where I want the keyboard to hide after editing a UITextView object. I have compared it to a working project (Apple's Keyboard Accessory example) and the only difference I can see is the order of objects under the View Controller. I can't figure out how to reorder them, but I am not sure if it is a problem. It appears that the wrong object is being selected as First Responder.
I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me if it is relevant and if so how to reorder the objects.
I'm attaching screenshots of both View Controllers. The Water View Controller screen shot is mine and the other one is the Keyboard Accessory example.

[image: Keyboard Accessory] [image: My View Controller]

Answer (score 0):

In general it does not really matter the order you see them in Document Outline.

You can change the order by dragging them around.

However, sometimes changing the order of 2 items can make some details become invisible, so make sure you always check any changes you make.

Hope it helped

Comment: I have attempted to drag the Accessory View, Done and Edit Buttons (individually) above the First Responder object ... no luck. I tried creating another View Controller with an Accessory View and could not get it to move above the First Responder.

Comment: Because there may be Auto-Layout constraints on your UI, that may not be possible all the times.

Comment: Can you suggest where I can find these auto-layout constraints.

Comment: They should also be visible in the Document Outline. You can also disable them if you want/need.

Comment: I've stripped the app down to just the view and navigation controllers and removed constraints but it still doesn't behave properly however, it appears that there is some object behind the Accessory view because if I click the keyboard some letters appear just above the keyboard (although the letters do not correspond to the letters I type - they are out by one letter - very strange.)

Comment: I removed the accessory view and am making progress. I can see the Text View and add the keyboard appears and disappears correctly. Now I have scrolling problems but that is another issue. Thanks for your help Pavlusha.